# Pydantic 2 - Editing alias after object generation

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to edit the alias value on a Pydantic model after it has been created:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

obj = MyModel(age=8, name='Brian')
field = obj.model_fields['name']
field.alias = 'full_name'

[IN]  obj.model_dump(by_alias=True)
[OUT] {
          'name': 'Brian',
          'age': 8,
      }
```

I would want the key `name` here to be `full_name`. I've tried using `model_construct` to rebuild a model, but I would need to edit the alias on the `MyModel` class I would guess, which I do not want to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### My Answer

- `alias` (Field) is saved in the model class, not the instance.
- So modify the field of the model, then rebuild.

### My Example

```py
from pydantic import VERSION, BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo

print(VERSION)
# > 2.4.2


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


obj = MyModel(age=8, name='Brian')


MyModel.model_fields['name'] = FieldInfo.merge_field_infos(
    MyModel.model_fields['name'], Field(alias='full_name')
)
MyModel.model_rebuild(force=True)


print(obj.model_dump(by_alias=True))
# > {'full_name': 'Brian', 'age': 8}
```

Comment: Just in case someone wants to know more about this, here's a relevant GH issue: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7422